# Any proper way to sort a MySQL query before you group the result

Tags: mysql

I have a query which combines 3 tables and I need to sort the results from each group of the group By clause. 
The result are the orders from all users on a certain period. Each order consist of various products. So on my result I have the total cost of each order and the order id is where I use the group By in order to have only one result from each order with the total cost. But then I need to sort by the total order cost from each user in descending order.
The result is the following.

[image: grouped table]

The MySQL query that I have is the below, but when I add the ORDER BY clause then I cannot have all the usernames together.

```
SELECT
  u.user_id AS uid,
  u.user_name AS username,
  u.user_lastname AS lastname, 
  o1.order_id AS oid,
  SUM(o2.product_sum) AS SUMA 
FROM user AS u 
LEFT JOIN orders AS o1 ON u.user_id = o1.user_id
LEFT JOIN ordered_items AS o2 ON o1.order_id = o2.order_id 
WHERE o1.order_date BETWEEN '2020-02-17' AND '2020-03-27' 
GROUP BY oid
```

Comment: What `order by` are you adding? What is the result you want?

Comment: add `ORDER BY oid,SUMA DESC` to the end of the SQL.

Comment: @danblack, if I add this then it will sort all results and will mix the usernames. I need to sort only the results from each user. So the 6th row to be before the 5th for example. And if I add both oid and SUMA I get the same result as above

Comment: `order by uid, suma desc`?

Answer (score 0):

As @Schwen wrote this is what worked.

ORDER BY uid, suma DESC